# Replace a specific line keeping identation

Tags: text-processing, sed, regular-expression, whitespace

I have a file that has indentation.
I want to replace a specific line but keep the indentation.
The file has a line such as

```
   \t\t     customerId = "123" // has indentation in the start of line
```

I am running this:

```
sed  -e 's:^\s*customerId = "'${OLD_ID}'": customerId = "'${NEW_ID}':' file
```

This does not do anything. Also I am aware that even if it worked I would mess up the indentation.
How can I fix this?
**Note:** Solution doesn't have to be `sed` but I would like it to be able to be cross-platform

**UPDATE**
Tested @Gilles Quenot answer:

```
OLD_ID="1234"  
NEW_ID="5678"  
sed -E -i.bk "s:^(\s*)versionName = \"$OLD_ID\":\1versionName = \"$NEW_ID\":"   testfile
```

Sample test:

```
name="Jim"
    customerId = "1234"
```

Number was not replaced

Comment: Does anchoring the start of the pattern to zero or more whitespace characters really achieve anything? Can't you just do `sed 's:customerId = "'${OLD_ID}'":customerId = "'${NEW_ID}'":'` or `sed '\:customerId: s:"'${OLD_ID}'":"'${NEW_ID}'":'` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using standard `sed`:

```
sed "s:^\([[:blank:]]*customerId = \)\"$OLDID\":\1\"$NEWID\":" file
```

The `[:blank:]` pattern will match a single space or tab character.

The `sed` expression captures everything on the line up to the ID itself, and replaces it with what was captured and the new ID.

Slightly nicer looking, possibly,

```
sed 's:^\([[:blank:]]*customerId = \)"'"$OLDID"'":\1"'"$NEWID"'":' file
```

Testing:

```
$ cat file
name="Jim"
    customerId = "1234"

$ OLDID=1234
$ NEWID=321

$ sed 's:^\([[:blank:]]*customerId = \)"'"$OLDID"'":\1"'"$NEWID"'":' file
name="Jim"
    customerId = "321"
```

If the spaces around the `=` are optional, you may want to use

```
sed 's:^\([[:blank:]]*customerId *= *\)"'"$OLDID"'":\1"'"$NEWID"'":' file
```

---

Another approach suggested by don_crissti in comments:

```
sed '/customerId *=/s/"'"$OLDID"'"/"'"$NEWID"'"/' file
```

This has the benefit that it does not need a capture group.  This looks for lines containing the word `customerId` followed by an equal sign and replaces the IDs on these rows.

Comment: So basically the problem was using the posix indicators? I thought `-E` would solve that but it does not

Comment: @Jim `\s` is not POSIX basic regular expression, nor a POSIX extended regular expression, but a PCRE ("Perl regular expression"). Some implementations of `grep` may support this with `-P`, but `sed` probably doesn't.

Comment: `\s` and `\S` are very much supported by `gnu sed` since they are `gnu` [regular expression extensions](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#regexp-extensions). On another note - if `customerId` can only appear in `key = value` pairs then simply replace `${OLD_ID}` with `${NEW_ID}` on lines that match `customerId`  and that will preserve all spacing.

Comment: @don_crissti Thanks Don. I don't use the GNU tools too much, so I'm definitely not an authority on them. Thanks for the other suggestion too, I'll make an update soon.

Comment: No problem, I know you're a BSD guy so I thought I'd leave a note about that (and a link).

Answer (score 1):

```
sed -E "s:^(\s*)customerId = \"$OLD_ID\":\1customerId = \"$NEW_ID\":" file
```

Comment: Check my update in the post please